# Update list of dictionaries with a new key pair

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries:

```
my_list = [{'question_text': 'question text'}, {'question_text': 'question text'}]
```

I need to update `my_list` so it will look like:

```
my_list = [{'question_text': 'question text', 'answer_text': 'answer text'},
           {'question_text': 'question text', 'answer_text': 'answer text'}]
```

I will need to do `my_list` update in the for loop, because data for the `answer_text` comes from other list.

**Edit:**
I can change the way I initialize `my_list`, by placing an empty sting as value for `answer_text`

```
my_list = [{'question_text': 'question text', 'answer_text': ''},
           {'question_text': 'question text', 'answer_text': ''}]
```

Comment: such a list should initially be comprised of 'question'/'answer' pairs to set the correct relations

Comment: So far, so good. What problem are you having?

Comment: Are you asking how to append things to a list?

Answer (score 0):

```
for _dict in my_list:
    _dict['answer_text'] = 'answer text'

print my_list
```

Result is:

```
[{'question_text': 'question text', 'answer_text': 'answer text'},{'question_text': 'question text', 'answer_text': 'answer text'}]
```